# Visual Studio C# Print All Tabs in TabControl

Tags: c#, xaml

I am trying to print all the tabs in a tab control using PrintDialog but cannot seem to get it to work. The way I would like it to work would be print the MainGrid item with each toggled tab on a new page (right now its a new print job). So here I would have two pages both a printout of MainGrid with the tabs toggled differently on each page. I tried using the TabControl's selectedIndex but it doesn't work right. I have posted my xaml and the print function that does not work, Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<Window x:Class="PrintTabs.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PrintTabs"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="500">
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="54"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="93"/>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="Header">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Content="Header" Grid.Row="0"></Label>
            <Button x:Name="PrintThis" Content="Print" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="PrintMe" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="Info" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Content="Content:" Grid.Row="0"/>
        </Grid>
        <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.Row="2">
            <TabItem>
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Tab1" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </TabItem.Header>
                <Grid x:Name="Tab1Grid">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Content="some stuff"></Label>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem>
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Tab2" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </TabItem.Header>
                <Grid x:Name="Tab2Grid">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition x:Name="fieldHeader" Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Content="some more stuff"></Label>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

```
private void PrintMe(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        PrintDialog print = new PrintDialog();

        if (print.ShowDialog() == true)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                this.tabControl.SelectedIndex = i;
                print.PrintVisual(this.MainGrid, "Report");
            }


        }
    }
```

Requested output images

tab1 result
[image: tab1 result]

tab2 result
[image: tab2 result]

Comment: Can you post an image of the output you get. ?

Comment: You probably need to make this an `async` method and then `await` something (even if it's just `Task.CompletedTask`) after assigning to `SelectedIndex` in order to yield control long enough for it to update the surface.

Comment: And then "be kind, rewind" by setting `SelectedIndex` back to its original value.

Comment: I think it sounds like I do need to allow a pause for the visual to update. Can you give an example of how this is done. Thank you.

Comment: I was hoping it would lead someone more familiar with XAML than I to the right answer but I'll take a crack at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awaiting `Task.CompletedTask` as I suggested in the comments won't work.  I examined the generated state machine code and saw that when a task is returned in a completed state, the state machine jumps to the next step without yielding.

I'm not aware of a pre-made task that starts in an incomplete state and somehow automatically changes to a completed state without having to have a predefined time.  The trick here is to get the state machine's check for completion to fail before the timer sets the task to completed so that it yields but not wait too long so that you're wasting time.  As hardware gets better, what's enough time today may one day be insufficient.

*If there's a better way or a mechanism such as the one I described, I welcome the better answer.*

```
private async Task PrintMe(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PrintDialog print = new PrintDialog();

    int savedSelectedIndex = this.tabControl.SelectedIndex;

    if (print.ShowDialog())  // == true is redundant; don't do that.
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.tabControl.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            this.tabControl.SelectedIndex = i;

            // Allow the UI to update by yielding to the message loop
            // or whatever it is that controls the UI thread.
            await Task.Delay(100);

            print.PrintVisual(this.MainGrid, "Report");
        }
    }

    // And of course, "be kind, rewind"
    this.tabControl.SelectedIndex = savedSelectedIndex;
}
```

Note that the loop now uses `tabControl.Items.Count` instead of hard-coding the tab count.  That will help with maintenance if you ever change the number of tabs.

Now that `PrintMe` is `async`, you'll need to deal with that upstream.  Lacking context, that's as much advice as I can give you on that.

Comment: This did not quite work in its stock form but it got me close enough that I was able to get it working. Small change required was instead of using async Task PrintMe. I used async void PrintMe. Then it works. I'm not savvy enough to know if this is poor form but it functions.

Comment: It's generally considered to be something to avoid if you can. `async void` doesn't allow the call site to resync with an `await` but if you don't need that, you should be okay.

Comment: I stumbled upon what is probably a better solution while trying to determine how to print multiple pages. Instead of an async with delay one can use this.UpdateLayout() to achieve the same.

Comment: If you're saying that works then I'd agree that it's a better solution.